# Why isn't my while loop, looping?

Tags: python

I'm using notepad++ and I do this:

> x = raw_input("blablabla")

But it's printing onto the console, why is that? Shouldn't it just set the variable x to that command instead of printing?

Though my problem isn't from this, I still don't understand why does a variable prompts without being called, shouldn't it be called only when I "print x"?
====================EDIT=======================

```
str = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))

def numero(x):
    y = 0
    while x != 0:
        y += x
        return y
    else:
        print y

print numero(str)
```

Anyways, this isn't looping, my objective is here to add the numbers as long as user is inputing numbers until he inputs 0 which cancels and delivers the total..
I input a number and it goes right to printing the total without asking me for more numbers..

Comment: Are you looking for an iterator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is normal behaviour. You want to get an input from user. It is just a [**`prompt`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) for user input.
Actually 'blabla..' isn't part of value of variable `x`.

```
>>> x = raw_input("blablabla")
blablabla # waiting for further input...
```

Same behaviour in python command line.

```
>>> x = raw_input("Please insert some text...\n")
>>> print x
Please insert some text...
My cool variable!
My cool variable! # current value of x
```

Just use as:

```
x = raw_input()
```

update:

> I still don't understand why does a variable prompts without being
>   called, shouldn't it be called only when I "print x"?

Printing of prompt initiated by call of `raw_input('prompt')`

Try this:

```
def numero():
    return int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))

x = numero()
y = 0
while x != 0:
    y += x
    x = numero()
else:
    print 'Total y:', y
```

Comment: But I don't want to use that right away, I only want it to ask when I desire, when I later in the code put the variable to use..

Comment: Yes I got it wrong, I thaught the problem was is my variable but it isn't, problem is being in my loop which isn't looping

Comment: Sorry mate, I can't still get it. I understand that the variable is what the user writes, but I don't understand is why it runs without printing the variable X which is the raw_input

Comment: I'm chocked in how it worked out and you just put the while outside the function, why is that?

Comment: @J.Pinheiro your problem is that you `str = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))` expecting input from user just once. it should be inside `while`

Comment: @J.Pinheiro since it isn't inside `while` loop we can't expect more than just one value..